# Index violation on a referenced class, Morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, java-ee-6, morphia

I am trying to persist a one (Owner) to many (Car) relation with morphia(0.99)/mongoDB(2). When I try to persist class Car with a reference to class Owner, Morphia throws an MongoException$DuplicateKey exception. This is strange since I thought that cascade persisting didn't existed in morphia.

Why is morphia throwing a duplicate key exception for index *index_username* on the referenced class Owner when I persist Car?

Pojo:

```
@Entity(noClassnameStored=true, value="base")
public class Base {

    @Id
    private ObjectId id;
    ...


@Entity(value = "owner", noClassnameStored = true)
@Polymorphic
public class Owner extends Base {

    @Indexed(value = IndexDirection.ASC, unique=true, dropDups=true, name="index_username")
    private String userName;

    @Reference
    private Set<Car> cars = new HashSet<Car>();
    ... 

@Entity(value="car", noClassnameStored=true)
@Polymorphic
public class Car extends Base{
    @Reference
    private Owner owner
```

Bean:

```
car.setOwner(owner);
BeanUtil.getDataStore().save(car);
```

Exception:

```
com.mongodb.MongoException$DuplicateKey: E11000 duplicate key error index: myapp.car.$index_username  dup key: { : null }
```

Comment: I should say that persisting the first Car object with reference to Owner works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add more than one `null` reference. Either add a value for all entities (up to 1 may be `null`) or set `sparse=true` on the index so you can have unique values, but allow multiple `null`

Comment: I had to delete/drop the whole DB, then it started to work. Guess that it cached the index from before somehow ?!
What does Sparse mean in Morphia, the java doc don't explain much (except allow null values) ?

Comment: Strange that you had to drop the whole DB - would have assumed that dropping the index would have been sufficient. Sparse tells the index, that it should ignore null values on unique checks; so you can have multiple null values while all non-nulls need to be unique. Hope that makes it clearer.